# .htaccess 301 redirects based on TLD

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

We're in the process of switching our current site from a multiple domain configuration into a single domain, multiple folder format. i.e.

`.co.uk/<uri>` is becoming `.com/en-gb/<uri>`

`.com/<uri>` is becoming `.com/en-us/<uri>`

I'm hoping that I'll be able to handle this via a couple of well-crafted .htaccess rules, but I'm not sure of code I'm going to need to achieve this. Can you help?

(PS, I've left the actual domain blank, as we only need to test for the TDL, not the entire domain - although whatever the original domain was need to stay the same, with only the TLD changing - i.e. `whatever.co.uk` would redirect to `whatever.com/en-gb/`, `whatever2.co.uk` would redirect to `whatever2.com/en-gb/`, and `whatever.com` would redirect to `whatever.com/en-us/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following directives to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.com/en-gb/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en-us|en-gb)/
RewriteRule (.*) /en-us/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

if you have so many domain TLDs, you maybe want to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) to avoid duplicating the first rule for every TLD, RewriteMap will map TLD to Uri string (ex: .co.uk to en-gb),

Comment: This is fantastic, works exactly as intended, thank you very much.

Comment: I do have one further question - because we're using physical folders (i.e. `/en-gb/`), I figured, rather than having the `!^/(en-us|en-gb)/` part of the rule, is there not some code we can use in a `.htaccess` file, within the `/en-gb/` folder, that will negate the above rule? I ask because we're going to be adding more folders in the near future (`/de-de/` being our next one), so rather than having to update the root rules for each folder, we can simply copy the `.htaccess` file from existing `/en-gb/` for each new one.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you are using the directives I have posted in every TLD folder .htaccess, you could move the code above in a new .htacess in the root folder (one level up /en-gb/), and set DocumentRoot in virtualhost configuration of all domains to the this root folder (but make sure this does not interfere with existing rules).